# How to hide or remove empty cells on a <tr> when more cells exist in <th> than in <tr>?

Tags: html, css

As you can see below, I have 7 th tags and only 3 td tags all in the same thead. This displays like the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzTDQ.png). I want to remove or hide the empty cells without hiding the entire row. 
Any ideas?

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="af1067-col header"></th>
    <th class="priority-col header"></th>
    <th class="project-id-col header"></th>
    <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q1</th>
    <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q2</th>
    <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q3</th>
    <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="input-filter-td">
        <input class="column-filter cell-content" data-target="af1067-col" type="text">
    </td>
    <td class="input-filter-td">
        <input class="column-filter cell-content" data-target="priority-col" type="text">
    </td>
    <td class="input-filter-td">
        <input class="column-filter cell-content" data-target="project-id-col" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So, you want to hide the `<th>`'s with class `budget-color-3400` ? Then just add `.budget-color-3400{display:none;}` to your css

Comment: No i want to hide the extra td cells that are empty underneath the 4 (7-3) theads

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide just the empty cells `td` within the `thead` simply set `display:none` to `budget-color-3400` or  you can use Class Selector (if your class has different values):

```css
.header {
  background: red;
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
}
#selector [class*="-color"] {
  display: none
}
#class .budget-color-3400 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<table id="selector">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="af1067-col header">Tracking ID
      </th>
      <th class="priority-col header">Priority
      </th>
      <th class="project-id-col header">Project ID
      </th>
      <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q1</th>

      <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q2</th>

      <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q3</th>

      <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="input-filter-td">
        <input class="column-filter cell-content" data-target="af1067-col" type="text">
      </td>
      <td class="input-filter-td">
        <input class="column-filter cell-content" data-target="priority-col" type="text">
      </td>
      <td class="input-filter-td">
        <input class="column-filter cell-content" data-target="project-id-col" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<hr />
<table id="class">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="af1067-col header">Tracking ID
      </th>
      <th class="priority-col header">Priority
      </th>
      <th class="project-id-col header">Project ID
      </th>
      <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q1</th>

      <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q2</th>

      <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q3</th>

      <th class="budget-color-3400 header">Q4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="input-filter-td">
        <input class="column-filter cell-content" data-target="af1067-col" type="text">
      </td>
      <td class="input-filter-td">
        <input class="column-filter cell-content" data-target="priority-col" type="text">
      </td>
      <td class="input-filter-td">
        <input class="column-filter cell-content" data-target="project-id-col" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
[class*="-col"]:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

The trick will be to make sure there's no whitespace in the container, therefore making it fit the `:empty` pseudo selector.